# Android - Cropping Image library

Tags: android

Is there an image cropping library that returns Uri content?

Each one I tried is returned by the Uri file.

The problem I have is that when I load an image I took from the camera, I want to crop it and send it to the server. Submission is done via contentResolver waiting for content Uri.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch camera take URI from this methods:

```
private fun createImageURI(): Uri? {

    val imageCollection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    else
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

    val imageName = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "$imageName")
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    }

    val finalURI = contentResolver.insert(imageCollection, contentValues)
    resultUri = finalURI
    return finalURI
}

private fun createVideoURI(): Uri? {

    val imageCollection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    else
        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

    val imageName = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "$imageName.mp4")
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/MPEG-4")
    }

    val finalURI = contentResolver.insert(imageCollection, contentValues)
    resultUri = finalURI
    return finalURI
}
```

Like this:

```
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).apply {
        putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, "your uri")
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, 10)
```

Now startActivityForResult is deprecated you can use ActivityContract api like this:

```
takePhotoContract =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { status ->
            if (status) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                resultUri?.let {
                    loadImage(it)
                }
            } else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

Pass resultUri into your CropActivity:

```
private fun launchImageCrop(uri: Uri) {
    mContext?.let {
        CropImage.activity(uri)
            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
            .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
            .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE)
            .start(it, this)
    }
}
```

You can manually crop image or use this library:
[Android Image Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

Refer this: [Demo App](https://github.com/absolute-vijju/ActivityContract)